# How to use pathlib to process paths that begin with ~?

Tags: python, pathlib

I am writing a cli-tool that needs some path as input.

I am writing this tool in python and would like to use no python interpreter below 3.6. Using the package`pathlib`seems to be the modern way to go when dealing with paths in python. So I would like to leave `os` and `os.path` behind if possible.

It seems like pathlib interprets the path `~/test/` as a relative path to the current working directory, the code below shows it

```py
import pathlib

test_path = pathlib.Path('~/test')
absolute_path = test_path.absolute()

print(f"{str(test_path):>31}\n{str(absolute_path):>31}")
# output:
#              ~/test
# /home/myUser/~/test
```

How can I use pathlib to recognize every path starting with `~` as an absolute path and automatically expand `~` into the users home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy, use `.expanduser()` on your Path object instead of `.absolute()`and it will replace ~ with the home directory of the user running the script, the result is also an absolute path only if ~ is at the beginning:

```py
import pathlib

test_path = pathlib.Path('~/test')
absolute_path = test_path.expanduser()
# If ~ is somewhere in the middle of the path, use .resolve() to get an absolute path.

print(f"{str(test_path):>31}\n{str(absolute_path):>31}")
# output:
#            ~/test
# /home/myUser/test
```

Comment: `expanduser` will not make paths  absolute if they do not start with `~`.

Comment: @Sneftel So how do you get a flexible result, where the path is absolute whether it starts with `~` or not?

Comment: Well, you use both.

Comment: Then why isn't that part of your answer?

Comment: I added the note as a comment in code, it wasn't part of my original answer because for paths starting wit `~` , `.expanduser()` will yield an absolute path and `.resolve()` is not needed.